# Ionic 2 ajax JSON data to ngFor

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

1. I have script.php which create json array with data from mySQL;

   2. Next
      step - I got this json array via AJAX ;
   3. I want to create divs in loop via ngFor, **but I have no idea how I can callback this json array from Ajax success function**.

Thanks for help!

**Home.html**

```
    <ion-list *ngFor="let data of displayData" no-lines>
      <ion-item>Text: {{ data.text }} - Value: {{ data.value }}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**Home.ts - Don't working**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
      pages: string = "app";

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

      }

      ionViewDidLoad(): any {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://example.com/data.php",
          data: {
            first : "first"
          },
          success: function(data){
           displayData = JSON.parse(data);// Getting JSON
          error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
          }
        })
      }
}
```

**Home.ts - Working**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  pages: string = "app";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  displayData = [{
    "text": "item 1",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "item 2",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "text": "item 3",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "text": "item 4",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "text": "item 5",
    "value": 5
  },
  ];
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://example.com/data.php",
      data: {
        first : "first"
      },
      success: function(data){
        alert("good!");
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log("error");
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but... why are you using jQuery? You better use the Angular's http client: https://angular.io/guide/http. Answering you r question, you have to set this.displayData with the array that has been returned from your API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm new in Angular 2, and this framework so hard for me now, coz i don't understand why i need include httpMudule component in app.module.ts then I need declare this module in app.module.ts, after I get the opportunity to include Http in my home.ts, and after this moves i can write this.http.get('http://example.com/data.php'). WHY SO HARD? I want to just include jquery, i have no idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid use of jQuery. Use Angular' tools, like the Http client.
Then, set the array to the displayData.

```
export class HomePage {
  pages: string = "app";
  displayData = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.http.get('http://niceshot.pro/data.php')
    .map( data => data.json() )
    .subscribe( parsed_data => {
      this.displayData = parsed_data;
    })
}
```